# Programatically get full path to binary in powershell (which, where, Get-Command)

Tags: windows, powershell, bash, scripting, path

How do I get the absolute path to a given binary and store it to a variable?

What is the equivalent to the following for Linux Bash in Windows Powershell?

```
user@disp985:~$ path=`which gpg`
user@disp985:~$ echo $path
/usr/bin/gpg
user@disp985:~$ 

user@disp985:~$ $path
gpg: keybox '/home/user/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
```

In Windows Powershell, there's `Get-Command`, but the output is hardly trivial to parse programmatically for a script.

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-Command gpg.exe
 
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     gpg.exe                                            2.2.28.... C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuP...
 
 
PS C:\Users\user>
```

How can I programmatically determine the full path to a given binary in Windows Powershell, store it to a variable, and execute it?

Comment: `hardly trivial to parse`? PowerShell is object oriented, there is no need to parse anything. It's not going to get more trivial.

Comment: Apart from that, the question is off topic, programming questions belong on [so]. Chances are high that this question was already answered there.

Comment: I agree it's off topic on server fault

Comment: not sure how typing commands into a powershell terminal is programming, seems like Server Fault to me..

Comment: Usually it's not necessary to get an object's preferences as a (string type) variable. Just use it whereever you are. The "closest" thing to a batch (bash) string-output would be `Get-Command format | Format-List Source`, which would be fairly easy to parse.

Answer (score 2):

For the example command provided by the OP question:

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-Command gpg.exe
 
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     gpg.exe                                            2.2.28.... C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuP...
 
 
PS C:\Users\user>
```

You can extract the "Source" field with the following syntax

```
PS C:\Users\user> $(Get-Command gpg.exe).Source
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe
```

Then you can also store it to a variable and execute it with an ampersand (&) preceding the variable

```
PS C:\Users\user> $path=$(Get-Command gpg.exe).Source
PS C:\Users\user> echo $path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe
PS C:\Users\user> & $path
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
```